# Sippy VOIP, API requests XML or JSON. Authentication failure

Tags: xml, authentication, curl, call, voip

I am having problem in implementing the Sippy APIs.
There is no much support or well documentation about this service.

I need to know is there anybody had worked onto this.
I just need how to hit the request and get the response.

there documentation only explain the XML requests but not clear how to get success in that.

I run the curl command:

**Source** [https://support.sippysoft.com/support/solutions/articles/107327-xml-rpc-api-retrieving-account-information`](https://support.sippysoft.com/support/solutions/articles/107327-xml-rpc-api-retrieving-account-information%60)

```
curl -k --digest -u waleed:waleed001 -d '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<methodCall> <methodName>listCustomers</methodName> 
<params><param><value><struct> 
<member><limit>100</limit></member> 
</struct></value></param></params> 
</methodCall>' http://51.81.172.137/xmlapi/xmlapi
```

**Response**

> This server could not verify that you are authorized to
> access the document you requested.  Either you supplied the
> wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser
> does not understand how to supply the credentials required.

**Source** [https://support.sippysoft.com/support/solutions/articles/107327-xml-rpc-api-retrieving-account-information`](https://support.sippysoft.com/support/solutions/articles/107327-xml-rpc-api-retrieving-account-information%60)